# Feynman rules for Gross-Neveu (four fermion) model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, fermions, interactions

I'm having hard times in finding the Feynman rules for the Gross-Neveu model in two dimensions:
$$ \mathcal L = \bar \psi^i (i \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} ) \psi^i + g^2 (\bar \psi^i \psi^i )^2 \; ,$$
where $i = 1, \ldots, N$ and $\mu = 1, 2$. Moreover $\gamma^0 = \sigma^2$ and $\gamma^1 = i\sigma^1$ where $\sigma^i$ are the Pauli matrices.

The propagator is obvious:
[image: fermion propagator]

while the 4-point diagram should be:
[image: 4 point Feynman diagram]

---

**Question**: How are the $\epsilon$'s defined? Where they come from?

Moreover, since any propagator brings two Dirac index, one at the beginning and one at the end of the propagator, there shouldn't be another Dirac index at the center of the four-point diagram?

Comment: Are you sure those are $\epsilon$s and not $\gamma$s?

Comment: @SounakSinha Yes, moreover it seems they obey the following relation:
$$ \epsilon_{a b} \frac{1}{\gamma^{\mu}_{bc}} \epsilon_{cd} = \gamma^{\mu}_{ad} $$

This is the source: https://zzxianyu.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/peskin_problems.pdf
see from page 93

Comment: The gamma matrices are $2\times2$. So I guess those are the Levi civita tensors of two dimensions.

Comment: @SounakSinha I update the post with some information about the $\gamma$ matrices used.

Why there should be a Levi Civita tensor? Does it reflect the anti-commutation of spinors? Why they does not appear in ordinary QED?

Comment: Ordinary QED is four dimensional so there is no two dimensional antisymmetric tensor. Also, note that the gamma matrices have been expressed in terms of the Pauli matrices. Since $\gamma^0$ (which can be expressed in terms of the Levi Civita tensor) appears in the interaction term of the Lagrangian, it'svthere in the Feynman interaction vertex.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think those should be Kronecker deltas in the spinor indices, not Levi Civita symbols. I think the author of those homework solutions was intending to include the $\gamma^0_{ab}=-i\epsilon_{ab}$ part of $\bar{\psi}$ in the vertex, but if you do that you would need an extra factor of $\gamma^0$ in the propagator. I am not writing this as an answer because I am not 100% sure, but I have indeed found mistakes in those solutions to Peskin problems before so beware.

Comment: I have worked out the confusion about the Kronecker deltas in the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/750001/fermi-statistics-in-the-feynman-rules-for-the-gross-neveu-model/750493#750493).